# MySQL or PostgreSQL for Hibernate + JPA2 project

Tags: mysql, postgresql, jpa-2.0

I want to confirm which is better, I have seen that polls say that PostgreSQL is way ahead of MySQL in terms of speed with JPA/Hibernate.

Want some feedback based on speed, reliability, compatibility etc. before I make the final decision on which to use.

Comment: Use the one you are comfortable working with. MySQL has issues with its [ACIDity](http://www.wikivs.com/wiki/MySQL_vs_PostgreSQL#ACID_Compliance). For things like speed, performance, it is too early. Make a great app that people want to use. You can tackle speed when it becomes a bottleneck.

Comment: This question will probably be closed as "not constructive" because it's over-broad, subjective, and has no specific answer. See http://stackoverflow.com/faq#close, http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask, and http://stackoverflow.com/faq#dontask . There are lots of good places to ask MySQL vs PostgreSQL questions; this isn't really one of them. Everyone will suggest whichever DB they prefer and we'll all learn very little.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Either one can be faster than the other.

It depends on the workload and your DB design. MySQL has some performance features that PostgreSQL does not, but it seems that PostgreSQL scales better with have concurrent read and writes scenarios. But again: this depends heavily on how you use the system. I'm sure you can easily setup a test that proves that either one is faster than the other.

The query optimizer in PostgreSQL is more advanced than in MySQL and copes with complicated statements much better (especially when it comes to sub-selects)

As for reliability I think that PostgreSQL is more reliable (especially when compared to MySQL using MyISAM - InnoDB is a lot better here). The prime goal of the PostgreSQL developers is to first make sure the data is safe. But I do not have any hard facts to support this statement! It's just the feeling I get by reading several DBMS related forums. Problems with corruption *seem* to be more frequent with MySQL than with Postgres

In terms of (modern) SQL features MySQL is far behind of PostgreSQL (think check constraints, recursive queries, windowing functions, transactional DDL, ...). One thing that PostgreSQL is lacking is an equivalent of MySQL's `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE ...` feature (aka "merge" or "upsert").

MySQL's (table) partitioning is easier to setup and manage if that is important.

Compatibility with what? With the ANSI SQL standard? 
Then PostgreSQL is (much) better than MySQL.

Comment: Well luckily for anyone reading this in the future we have ON CONFLICT in postgres